# iPad - Is it possible to send SMS?

Tags: sms, ipad

Recent iPads are having provision to insert sim card in that.
So with latest iOS SDK, is it possible to send in-app SMS from my application.
I know that in-app sms is possible from iPhone. But how about iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the documentation seems a bit ambiguous on this. MFMessageComposeViewController's canSendText method returns NO if the iPad doesn't support text messages OR if not currently configured to send messages.

I always get NO so this makes me wonder where one configures an iPad with 3G to send messages? Or if my iPad with WiFi & 3G even support SMS?

I tried the Apple example code and read the 2010-10-15 "System Messaging Programming Topics for iOS".

This makes me wonder if only iPhones can send SMS messages?

Ciao